# Web-Based Java Compiler

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans, web-applications, compilation

I'm Trying to create an online compiler that takes the the code as a string from the web page and displays the output. I've created a servlet.The user will enetr the program code in a textarea named "uName". The code to take the input as a string and compile it is as follows

```
`enter code here`
/*
   * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
      * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Org.WebApplication1.test;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.SimpleJavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;

class CompileString {

    static String program;

    CompileString(String s)
    {

    program=s;
    }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();


    Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> fileObjects;
    fileObjects = getJavaSourceFromString(program);

    compiler.getTask(null, null, null, null, null, fileObjects).call();

    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("Test");
    Method m = clazz.getMethod("main", new Class[] { String[].class });
    Object[] _args = new Object[] { new String[0] };
    m.invoke(null, _args);
  }

  static Iterable<JavaSourceFromString> getJavaSourceFromString(String code) {
    final JavaSourceFromString jsfs;
    jsfs = new JavaSourceFromString("code", code);
    return new Iterable<JavaSourceFromString>() {
      public Iterator<JavaSourceFromString> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<JavaSourceFromString>() {
          boolean isNext = true;

          public boolean hasNext() {
            return isNext;
          }

          public JavaSourceFromString next() {
            if (!isNext)
              throw new NoSuchElementException();
            isNext = false;
            return jsfs;
          }

          public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
          }
        };
      }
    };
  }
}

class JavaSourceFromString extends SimpleJavaFileObject {
  final String code;

  JavaSourceFromString(String name, String code) {
    super(URI.create("string:///" + name.replace('.', '/') + Kind.SOURCE.extension), Kind.SOURCE);
    this.code = code;
  }

  public CharSequence getCharContent(boolean ignoreEncodingErrors) {
    return code;
  }
}

/**
 *
 * @author RAJ
 */



public class ServletExample extends HttpServlet{







    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //super.doGet(req, resp);



        String name=req.getParameter("uName");
        CompileString obj=new CompileString(name);
        String ip=req.getRemoteAddr();
        resp.getWriter().println("<html>");
        resp.getWriter().println("<head>");
        resp.getWriter().println("<tile>Respnse</title>");
        resp.getWriter().println("</head>");
        resp.getWriter().println("<body>");
        resp.getWriter().println("The output is "+obj);
        resp.getWriter().println("<br>");
        resp.getWriter().println("Your ip address is "+ip);
        resp.getWriter().println("</body>");
        resp.getWriter().println("</html>");


    }

}
```

I want to display the output of the CompileString Class but the output im getting is "Org.WebApplication.Test...@1bsvdg"

Comment: That is because you didn't provide an implementation for toString. If you don't, the one from the Object class is used. Are you sure you want to work on something this advanced, if you don't know that?

Comment: I know about toString() method. Could you please elaborate on how to override it and use it for solving this problem of displaying the output

Comment: public String toString(){
      String r="";
        String[] stringArray = Arrays.copyOf(_args, _args.length, String[].class);
        for(int i=0;i<stringArray.length;i++)
          r+=stringArray[i];  
        return r ;
    } This is not working. It shows a null pointer exception. I've also tried to return the jsfs string in toString() but that shows null.

Comment: And ... what is _args, _args.length supposed to be? You can't write a decent toString method for CompileString, since CompileString doesn't have any instance methods. Again: learn the basics first. Try and understand how the foundation works, before basing entire applications on faultive or non-existing knowledge of the basics.